# Ubuntu 16.06 mysql 5.6 file privileges

Tags: mysql

I have mysql 5.6 installed on Ubuntu 16.06.  I get an error on `LOAD DATA  INFILE` saying `(Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)`. I have tried to set `secure_file_priv`, in a config file but I don't even know if it is taking and it is not fixing the error.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215231/load-data-infile-error-code-13 did not work for you?

Comment: Dang.  I didn't find that in my searches.  And I forgot about my long-past experiences with apparmor!  Thanks!